# how to connect to another database in wordpress

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to connect with another database in WordPress and insert data into a new table. I am creating a new object of wpdb

```
$newconnection= new wpdb("localhost","username","password","databasename");
```

and then trying to insert the data:

```
$newdb->insert('tablename', array('fullname'=> $_REQUEST['fullname'],'email'=> $_REQUEST['email']);
```

but i am not able to insert the data into new table of the new database.

its showing the error "ERROR ESTABLISHING A DATABASE CONNECTION".

Please try to resolve my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the order of the constructor arguments in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/__construct/):

> `string $dbuser, string $dbpassword, string $dbname, string $dbhost`

You've got the arguments in the wrong order. Move the host to the end:

```
$newconnection= new wpdb("username","password","databasename","localhost");
```

Comment: No problem. If you could take a moment to mark the answer as accepted I'd appreciate it.